# why doesn't my background image change on click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, addeventlistener

i'm doing a react project, and in my project there's a functionality that changes the backgroundImages on click, but the image doesn't show. Something changes, but the image doesn't show.
And i'm positive i got the right path.
I would appreciate som insight. Thank you in advance.
Here is the code:

```
export function theme_switcher(){
    let value = true;
    let btn_theme_switcher = document.getElementById("theme-switcher");
    function toggle(){
        if(value){
            black_theme();
            value = false;
        } else {
            white_theme();
            value = true;
        }
    }
    btn_theme_switcher.addEventListener("click", () => {
        toggle();
    })
}

function white_theme(){
    console.log("white");
    document.getElementById("background-img").style.backgroundImage = 'url("../images/bg-mobile-dark.jpg")';
    document.getElementById("background-img").style.backgroundPosition = "center";
    document.getElementById("background-img").style.backgroundSize = "cover";
}
function black_theme(){
    console.log("black");
    document.getElementById("background-img").style.backgroundImage = 'url("../images/bg-mobile-dark.jpg")';
    document.getElementById("background-img").style.backgroundPosition = "center";
    document.getElementById("background-img").style.backgroundSize = "cover";
}
```

This is in another file:

```
export default function ReactUseEffect(){
    React.useEffect(() => {
        theme_switcher();
        default_task_counter();
        delete_listener();
        completed_listener();
    });
    return(null);
}
```

Here is the live version: https://todo-list-lac-ten.vercel.app/
Here is my github: https://github.com/OrlandoVSilva/todo-list.git

*Forgot to tell you where to click. Its in the moon icon. Sorry!

Comment: perhaps set a breakpoint in there to see if its invoked?

Comment: If this is react, why are you doing it this way?

Comment: Show more of your component.  You shouldn't need to go through the DOM API directly if you are doing this in React.

Comment: https://todo-list-lac-ten.vercel.app/images/bg-mobile-dark.jpg vs https://todo-list-lac-ten.vercel.app/static/media/bg-desktop-light.3508d620.jpg

Comment: @zero298,i edited the question, to show more of the component, hope its enough!

Comment: cause black and white refence the same image? /images/bg-mobile-dark.jpg")

Comment: @Strella the dupplicate path its just an example, it doesnt work with any image i put

Comment: @epascarello, i'm sorry i dont understand your comment, my project doesnt work with any path i put, whether is in the same folder or another.

Comment: Are you _sure_ you're sure you have the right path?  Your initial page load reads the images from `/static/media/`, not `/images`. (I'm guessing that `images` is the path in your dev environment, and the assets get moved to `/static/media/` on build.). Your code also tries to change the image itself to 'bg-mobile-dark.jpg' for both light and dark modes... that image doesn't seem to exist in either folder.

Comment: (I have to agree with the other comments that this is not a good way to use React; you really should be controlling this with a state variable toggling a classname, instead of rummaging around in the DOM making direct modifications that React doesn't know about)

Answer (score 2):

That's mostly because you used `value` as a variable. You should use [useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) for handling component states. But such effect can also be achieved using css

JS:

```
function ThemeSwitcher() {
    const [dark, setDark] = useState(false);

    return (
        <div className='...' >
            <div className={`bg${dark ? ' bg--dark' : ''}`} />
        </div>
    );
}
```

CSS:

```css
.bg {
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;

    background-image: url("../images/bg-mobile-white.jpg");
}

.bg.bg--dark {
    background-image: url("../images/bg-mobile-dark.jpg");
}
```

Also while using React you should really forget about methods like `getElementbyId` or `addEventListener` as it has way better solutions for this.

Answer (score 0):

`theme_switcher` is called via `React.useEffect` but I think callbacks should be called via `React.useEffect` as well so instead of calling `black_theme();`, try calling `React.useEffect(black_theme);`
Also all this is probably against every common React practice
Even if let's say `background-img` is somehow outside of your React scope (whatever this means) then at least `value` should be a state variable

Answer (score 0):

i appreciate the help ALOT, but i managed to get ot work with this:

```
import backgroundPic from "../images/bg-mobile-dark.jpg"
//-----------------------------------------------
export default function ContentHeaders(){
    const change_theme =  () => {
        let background = document.getElementById("background")
        background.style.backgroundImage = `url(${backgroundPic})`
    }
    return(
        <div id = "header">
            <h1>TODO</h1>
            <div id = "theme-switcher" onClick = {change_theme}></div>
        </div>
    );
}
```